# Not able to get tooltip text using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, tooltip

I have 5 tooltips in page. Using WebDriver, I am trying to verify these tooltip text.

I am using following code sequentially to get the tooltip text of all 5 elements:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriver);
builder.ClickAndHold(Element1).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element1ToolTip.text);

builder.ClickAndHold(Element2).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element2ToolTip.text);

builder.ClickAndHold(Element3).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element3ToolTip.text);
```

The issue is I get only the tooltip text of first element printed in console. 
Is it because I need to refresh or reset the builder?

It's really weird when I delete the code for 1st element , then I can get tooltip text of 2nd element. So, basically it is getting tooltip text only once in single execution.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if this would help but aren't tooltips supposed to be shown when you hover over them? Maybe the click is causing the issue? Isn't there a mouse over/hover action ?

Comment: This issue was logged under WebDriver : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2493

Answer (score 1):

Verify tool tip by comparing "title" attribute of the web element and your expected tool tip text.

```
Console.WriteLine(Element1.GetAttribute("title"));

Console.WriteLine(Element2.GetAttribute("title"));
```

Comment: There is no title attribute in my HTML code and the value of alt attribute is blank/empty. Please see the HTML code below:

<img width="25px" height="25px" src="/mkteditor/css/images/tooltip.png" alt="">

In this case, What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Tool tip text for input elements would be the title attributes and for images, alt attribute would be the tool tip.This is the standard for HTML 4, so I am not sure if you need to do hover and all.

```
Console.WriteLine(InputElement1.GetAttribute("title"));
Console.WriteLine(ImageElement1.GetAttribute("alt"));
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/toolmsg.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I think, it needs to release from element as:

```
builder.release(Element1).perform();
```

So, your code could be as below:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriver);
builder.ClickAndHold(Element1).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element1ToolTip.text);
builder.release(Element1).perform();

builder.ClickAndHold(Element2).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element2ToolTip.text);
builder.release(Element2).perform();

builder.ClickAndHold(Element3).Perform();
Console.WriteLine(Element3ToolTip.text);
builder.release(Element3).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue , i checked the view source page on running the test and it appears that the title attribute is displayed as data-original-title.Due to which it is unable to display the text.On replacing the title with data-original-title . I am able to obtain text.