# How to verify tooltipText in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, tooltip, selenium-webdriver

I have the following snippet of HTML code:

```
<div style="float:right; padding-right: 50px; margin-top: -10px;" id="divTooltips">
<img width="25px" height="25px" src="/mkteditor/css/images/tooltip.png" alt="">
</div>
```

During mouse over tooltip.png a tooltip text "help text at top place" is displayed. I want to verify the tooltipText in WebDriver. How to do it?

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739989/not-able-to-get-tooltip-text-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I tried the following:
action.clickAndHold(elemByXPath("//*[@id='divTooltips']/img")).perform();
String s = elemByXPath("//*[@id='divTooltips']/img").getText();
System.out.println("Tooltip: " + s);

Tooltip text was displayed when mouseover on the img, But no text was printed on my last line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you will have tooltip then "title" attribute will be there. (as per my observation ).

for example: Goto http://www.linkedin.com/ and view HTML code for LinkedIn image on top.
 LinkedIn

```
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com/");
    WebElement onElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/h2/a"));
    System.out.println("Tooltip : " + onElement.getAttribute("title"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If title attribute is there it is easy to get tooltip, But in my case there is no title attribute. this is the problem...

Comment: Having the title in an element doesn't mean that the tooltip will show up.

Answer (score 3):

My observation says, whenever you focus on element and a tool-tip appears it is displayed inside a "div" which is made visible on mouse focus.

Here is something i would suggest,

1. Move to element using [actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class

   > Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   >   action.moveToElement('element_to_be_focused').build().perform();
2. Now since tooltip displays some text, read that text and find out element from page source HTML where it is mentioned.
3. Now simply write code to wait for visibility of element having tooltip text.

   > new WebDriverWait(driver,
   >   timeOutInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated('element_locator'));
4. Get text from tooltip element using `getText()`

To give an example,
Click [here](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

On given website once we mouse hover to textbox asking for age, we can see tooltip saying 'We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.'

Following is code snippet to get tooltip text:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='age']"))).build().perform();
boolean isToolTipDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-tooltip-content']")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println("Is Tooltip displayed ? : " + isToolTipDisplayed);
            if (isToolTipDisplayed) {
                String tooltipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-tooltip-content']")).getText();
System.out.println("Tooltip Text:- " + tooltipText);
}
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.quit();
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Perfect Answer as no need to use the title everywhere. It needs to be changed as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.id("divTooltips");
 string titleText = element.getAttribute("title");
```

now the title is stored in a titleText string.In case tooltip is hidden and you want to see hidden text on it check [this](http://asktofolks.com/30/how-to-get-hidden-value-from-a-web-page-in-selenium-web-driver)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to verify the tooltip text:

```
try{
    String tooltipText = "help text at top place";
    String tooltipTextToVerify = driver.findElement(By.id("divTooltips").getAttribute("title");
      if (tooltipText.equels(tooltipTextToVerify)){
         return true;
      else {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
WebElement tooltipControl = driver.FindElement(By.id("divTooltips");
string titleText = tooltipControl.GetAttribute("textContent");
```

`textContent` attribute will provide the Text displayed in the tooltip.

Hope this will help you.